# How can I optimize this in order to make it run in less time?

Tags: python, performance, math, optimization

I have written a program which takes in argument an N value and generates N points with random coordinates between 0 and 1. These points are then associated with the red color if they are included in the circle of radii 1 centered on 0,0 and the blue color otherwise. The objective is to output a schematic including all the points and compute an approximated value of pi from these.

I would like to make the program run faster since the higher the N value, the higher the precision of it, but the longer it takes to run.
e.g I would like to run N=10 000 000

```
----------------main.py
#def
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from prototypes import point

r=0

#input
N=int(input("Nombre de tirages?"))

#compute
for N in range (1,N+1,1):
    [x,y]=point()
    if x**2 + y**2 > 1:
        plt.scatter(x,y, s=1, c='b')
    else:
        plt.scatter(x,y, s=1, c='r')
        r=r+1

p=((5/2)*N)/r

#output
plt.axis([0,1,0,1])
plt.title('Pour N={N}, une valeur approchée de Pi est {p}'.format(N=N,p=p))
plt.show()
```

```
----------------prototypes.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#create a random point
def point():
    x=random.random()
    y=random.random()
    return [x,y]
```

Comment: I would try in the for cycle to collect all the points in a list instead of directly plotting them! And at the end, calling scatter only once with the list of collected points.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I'm quite new to python and this forum, could you enlighten me about the way I could implement this?

Comment: small things matter: why declare a throwaway list here? `[x,y]=point()` - you could use `x,y = point()` instead. that are about 10k lists not to be constructed at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here's what I mean (I've put all together in one file just for simplicity):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#create a random point
def point():
    x=random.random()
    y=random.random()
    return x,y # no need for a list, lists needs extra memory space to maintain their structure, while you just need two numbers

r=0

#input
N=int(input("Nombre de tirages?"))

#compute
points_red = [] # This list will collect the red points
points_blue = [] # This list will collect the blue points
for N in range (1,N+1,1):
    x,y=point()
    if x**2 + y**2 > 1:
        points_blue.append((x,y)) # Add the point to list as a tuple (x,y)
    else:
        points_red.append((x,y)) # Add the point to list as a tuple (x,y)
        r=r+1

p=((5/2)*N)/r

#output
# The scatterplot is a slow and heavy operation: we just do it once plotting all the points collected in the two lists before at the same time
plt.scatter([p[0] for p in points_blue], [p[1] for p in points_blue], s=1, c='b')
plt.scatter([p[0] for p in points_red], [p[1] for p in points_red], s=1, c='r')
plt.axis([0,1,0,1])
plt.title('Pour N={N}, une valeur approchée de Pi est {p}'.format(N=N,p=p))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have a lot to learn about lists and how they behave! Furthermore, you just showed me how to correctly use the scatter function, which I can appreciate.